# Typescript check for base class

Tags: typescript

I need to pass a class to `handler` in the object down below:

```js
import { S01Handler } from "./handlers/start/S01Handler"


const config: ConfigInterface = {
    states: {
        [StateEnum.S01]: {
            objects: [
                BackgroundObject.NAME,
                LeavesObject.NAME,
            ],
            handler: S01Handler,
        },
    },
}
```

`S01Handler` extends an abstract base class `BaseHandler`. For example say `export abstract class BaseClass {}`

I want type-checking for `BaseClass` in handler entries.

My current `ConfigInterface` is not compatible for checking class types.

```js
type StateEnum = import("./StateEnum").StateEnum
type BaseHandler = import("../handlers/BaseHandler").BaseHandler
type ObjectName = string & {readonly '': unique symbol}


interface ConfigInterface
{
    states: {
        [key in StateEnum]: {
            objects: ObjectName[]
            handler: BaseHandler // I believe this checks for instance?
        }
    }
}
```

How should I change this to achieve `handler` type-checking?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want type-checking for BaseClass in handler entries."*? Do you mean you want to check that  the handler is derived from `BaseClass`?

Comment: Yes. Given that I am passing the actual class instead of an instance, it should theoretically be possible for the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of your question, but in your code you have the comment "I believe this checks for instance?" here:

```typescript
interface ConfigInterface
{
    states: {
        [key in StateEnum]: {
            objects: ObjectName[]
            handler: BaseHandler // I believe this checks for instance?
        }
    }
}
```

That comment is correct, it looks for an *instance* of `BaseHandler`. If you wanted to look for `BaseHandler` itself (the constructor function) or something that subclasses it, that would be `typeof BaseHandler`:

```typescript
interface ConfigInterface
{
    states: {
        [key in StateEnum]: {
            objects: ObjectName[]
            handler: typeof BaseHandler
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you may run into trouble trying to *use* `handler`, because it will also have the `abstract` part on it.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but I get `TS2693: 'BaseHandler' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`. Sorry, I am new to ts, It is due to how I import my `BaseHandler` in `d.ts` file. I can't use classes here due to 'ambient-context'

Comment: @silverflash - I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: I solved it, thank you! All I had to do was to replace `type BaseHandler = import("../handlers/BaseHandler").BaseHandler` with `declare abstract class BaseClass {} // with the actual signatures`. Could you edit that into your answer?

Comment: @silverflash - You don't have to do that in the normal case and I'm not entirely sure what it's doing, so best if I don't as I'd likely get something wrong. :-) Glad you figured it out!

Comment: You are right, there seems to be a discrepancy between my webstorm and webpack.